# Why does my Orangedox weekly summary show a high number (~500) every week, but not my stats?

Tags: orangedox

For months now I've been getting a weekly summary email from Orangedox telling me that my spreadsheet has been downloaded around 500 times. It looks like this (received today):

[image: Weekly notification email]

Not only did the number seem high, it also seemed odd that the file should be downloaded around 500 times every single week.

Now I finally got around to logging in to the Orangedox web app and I see these stats for the last 30 days:

[image: Download stats for last 30 days]

Eleven downloads is plausible. Is the number from the email (540) the result of a bug? Or is there another explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Orangedox weekly stats will show you **all** of your downloads and previews for this file (same as you'll see if you browse for the file though the app).  However the detailed analytic window within the app shows only **this weeks metrics** by default; you can change this time-frame by selecting the date in the top right hand corner (as shown in the modified screenshot below).

[image: Orangedox Screenshot]

Comment: side node - we may change the weekly status email to include only views during the previous week.